# How do you add a query string into link_to when using array notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

`link_to` allows you to specify the nested object path using an array:

```
= link_to(page.title, [page.magazine, page])
```

I can't figure out though how to add a query string onto this format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  The Array you are passing works because it is interpreted as an implicit polymorphic path, and passed to [`polymorphic_url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url).  The results are found using the routing table, and there isn't any built in support for additional params using this format.  If you need to extra params, use one of the alternative url-helper formats.